# How to filter JSON-Data with AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, json, frameworks, angularjs

I have an array (_users) that contains JSON objects.

```
{ 
  "User":
  {
    "userid":"19571",
    "status":"7",
    "active":"1",
    "lastlogin":"1339759025307",
    "Stats":
     [
       {
         "active":"1",
         "catid":"10918",
         "typeid":"71",
         "Credits":
         [
           {
             "content":"917,65",
             "active":"1",
             "type":"C7"
           },               
           {
             "content":"125,65",
             "active":"1",
             "type":"B2"
           }
         ]
       }
     ]
  }
}
```

1- How can I filter only users with "active":"1" not "0"

I have tried something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in _users | filter:active | orderBy:user.userid">
    {{user.userid}}
</div>
```

but not working correctly for me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Since your object model is kind of complex I would recommend using custom filtering function:

```
$scope.isActive = function(user) {
    return user.User.Stats[0].active === "1";
};
```

and then in your HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in _users | filter:isActive">
    {{user.User.userid}}
</div>
```

Here is the working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pkozlowski_opensource/4kzzy/3/

Be sure to check angular's documentation on filters if you need more info: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter

Comment: Answer above is perfect but FYI, if you want to filter your array before binding to scope, you can also use jQuery.grep() or the _filter from underscore.js

http://jsfiddle.net/NRuM7/1/ - jQuery.Grep()
http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#filter - underscore.js

Answer (score 4):

Taking @pkozlowski.opensource a bit further and allowing live filtering of items/users:

http://jsfiddle.net/hbyNN/

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <label>userid substring filter:</label>
  <input ng-model="zzzzz">

  <div ng-repeat="user in _users | filter:isInteresting"> 
      <pre>{{user | json}}</pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

And:

```
   $scope.isInteresting = function (user) {
    if ($scope.zzzzz == undefined) {
        return true;
    }

    return user.userid.indexOf($scope.zzzzz) !== -1;
};
```