# How to filter JSON Data with AngularJs

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

i have json data, and i want it show by filter such as genre.
Last question from [How to filter JSON-Data with AngularJs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11923142/how-to-filter-json-data-with-angularjs) dont work to me.

myapp.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('myApp', function($scope) { 

$scope.isoffice = function(apps) {
    return apps[0].genre === "office";
};

$scope.apps = [
    {
  "id": "stardict",
  "genre": "aksesoris", 
  "name": "Stardict"
},
{
  "id": "libreoffice",
  "genre": "office", 
  "name": "LibreOffice"
}];
}
```

my index.html

```
<div ng-repeat="app in apps | filter:isoffice">
  {{apps[0].name}}
</div>
```

do i missing somethink?
thank you..

Comment: apps[0].genre should be apps.genre

Comment: wow, thanks..
it work to me. both of them.. :))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need a comparator function to do that filtering.  You can use this:

```
<div ng-repeat="app in apps | filter:{genre:'office'}">
  {{app.name}}
</div>
```

Note that I use `app.name` to display the current app generated by `ngRepeat`.  `apps[0].name` will repeatedly display the first entry (if multiple entries match your filter).

[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5P5S5/1/)

If you want to use a comparator function, this will work (one object is sent in each time so you don't want to reference it as an array):

```
$scope.isoffice = function(apps) {
   return apps.genre === "office";
};
```

[comparator demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5P5S5/2/)

Comment: why if you do console.log(apps)the result is 4 object (2 for first row and 2 for second one)