# filter angularjs doesn't work in my case

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I add this into my `<li>` (line 5) but it returned blank.

```
| filter: {tabs.tabId: currentTab}
```

My app demo at http://jsfiddle.net/8Ub6n/8/

my html

```
 <ul ng-repeat="friend in user">
            <li ng-repeat="relation in friend.relationship">{{relation.name}} ({{relation.points}}points)</li>
        </ul>
```

here is my js

```
 $scope.user = [{
        'uId': 1,
            'name': 'Joe',
            'relationship': [{
            'uId': 2,
                'name': 'Jeremy',
                'tabs': [{
                'tabId': 1
            }],
                'tasks': [{
                'name': 'Im Jeremy Lin'
            }],
                'points': 50

        },{
            'uId': 2,
                'name': 'Michael',
                'tabs': [{
                'tabId': 1
            }],
                'tasks': [{
                'name': 'Im Jeremy Lin'
            }],
                'points': 80

        }]
    }]
})
```

have no idea what's wrong..

Comment: you haven't include the filter in you fiddle? In fact, there isn't anything relating to tabs in your fiddle. Maybe try and explain a little more, what you are trying to achieve

Comment: if I include it, it will gave a blank fiddle

Comment: @No1_Melman I expect it to return jemery and jordan since they have tabId = 1

Comment: You know your tabs is an array. Your trying to access an object...

Comment: And also that it is contained with in a sub object of user

Comment: @No1_Melman I know that that's why I am asking

Comment: Have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11923142/how-to-filter-json-data-with-angularjs)

Answer (score 1):

Done:

[Here it is](http://jsfiddle.net/8Ub6n/9/)

Just need to make another function in scope:

```
$scope.isTab = function (relation) {
   return relation.tab.tabId == $scope.currentTab;
}
```

then add to the filter:

```
relation in friend.relationship | filter : isTab
```

Comment: what is this for? 

var app = angular.module('myApp', []).filter('tabbed', function() {
  return function(input, currentTab) {
    return input == currentTab;
  };
});

Comment: @noob Ignore that, it was a test. that does nothing ;)

Comment: @noob it does work if you change the `currentTab` and click Run :)