# How can you filter objects by an array in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

was just wondering if you can filter an existing array with another array of filter.

So say our original json was:

```
[

   {
    "bookname": "harryporter",
    "year": "2000",
    "author":"J. K. Rowling"

   }, 

   {
    "bookname": "Sleepless",
    "year": "2003",
    "author":"Connie Ann Michael"

   },

   {
    "bookname": "No man's land",
    "year": "1993"
    "author":"Harold Pinter"

   }

];
```

**Filter array:**

```
[
"year":"1993"
"bookname":"No man"
]
```

Also is there a way to dynamically add elements to array when you edit input, perhaps type  in text ?

for example:

**Input**

```
<div>
<input type="text" ng-model={{ filterArray.insert("bookname":"value") }}>Book Name
</div>
```

**Filter**

```
<div ng-repeat="books in originalJson | filter: filterArray">
{{books.author}}
</div>
```

I hope i have explained my question enough, cheers

Comment: you don't filter json. json is just a string. you decode that json string into a native JS array/object and filter that.

Comment: Not exactly an array filter or Angular, but maybe close to what you're looking for in underscore.js [`where`](http://underscorejs.org/#where).

Comment: Take a look at this filtering: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11923142/how-to-filter-json-data-with-angularjs

Get your filtering values from input, then create a JS function that compares those values with the JSON data. Set that JS function as the 'filter:'

Comment: Why are you using an filter array and not an object?

Comment: sorry guys, i have updated the question by adding code, for some reason, it didnt show up

Comment: just make filterArray an object instead of array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to filter by multiple values, you can pass in a filter-object.
Each key corresponds to a field-name and each value filters the items based on the corresponding key.

```
Book name: <input type="search" ng-model="filterObj.bookname" />
Year:      <input type="search" ng-model="filterObj.year" />
<div ng-repeat="book in books | filter:filterObj">...</div>
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/9er1tbq4/)**.

---

If you want to let the user dymanically specify the field to filter by, you can do that too (although it is not very common practice):

```
Filter by:
<input type="search" ng-model="dynamicField"
       placeholder="Field to filter by" />
<input type="search" ng-model="filterObj[dynamicField]"
       placeholder="Value to filter by" />
<div ng-repeat="book in books | filter:filterObj">...</div>
```

Comment: thanks alot, but what i want is to dynamically insert the name of each ng-model for each input into an array so that in my filter i reference those model's i am basically building a dynamic website where angualar isn't aware of any input until add them using the config.json file. cheers

Comment: @Pizzy213codes: I don't quite get what you want to achieve (or why). Can't the `config.json` initialize the filterObj as well ? Did you study my demo ?

Comment: you have literally saved my life !!!!!!!, i have been on this for a day now !!! O_o Thanks so much, please could you recommend a good brush up angular js tutorial. I can use angualr, but lack substantial knowledge of it:(

Comment: @Pizzy213codes: The official tutorial is one of the best around. Egghead.io has some "must-watch" short videos on various concepts as well. **[This tutorial](http://www.thinkster.io/angularjs/GtaQ0oMGIl/a-better-way-to-learn-angularjs)** was my way into Angular (but I think it's more on beginner level, which you are obviously not). Make sure you carefully read the docs (API reference) and from there you just code-code-code and delve into the source-code.

Comment: @Pizzy213codes: (You might also want to regularly check up on the **[changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)** to see what has changed and what new features are available (or in beta).)