# Want to filter values from the JSON and add to array

Tags: angularjs, json, http

**In the following callback function in my angular JS app, I want only the values to be added in array addresses[ ] that have the value of val in the funtion parameter.
This is basically for the function to return values suggested based of string match from my json:**

```
$scope.getAirports = function(val) {
    return $http.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vedvasa/airports/master/airports.json', {
                              params: {
                                address: val,
                                sensor: false
                              }
                            }).then(function(res){

                              var addresses = [];
                              angular.forEach(res.data.records, function(item){
                              addresses.push(item.code);
                              });
                              return addresses;

                            });
                        };
```

Comment: Few things there API is taking in a parameter for val, what does key does val correspond to. Ideally this filtering should happen in the API itself.
Other option is to use [filters](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17193427/452708) in then()
Put your code on plnkr for easy reference https://plnkr.co/edit/GIApq3EbE0JvIT97BvG3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter JSON-Data with AngularJs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11923142/how-to-filter-json-data-with-angularjs)

Comment: @Abhijeet 
https://github.com/vedvasa/itinerary/blob/master/views/index.ejs

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter()` in your array

```
fetch("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vedvasa/airports/master/airports.json").
then(e => e.json()).
then(e => Promise.resolve(e.
    records.
    filter(e => e.carriers == 1))).
then(e => console.log(e.length))
```

Show this log `1655` at difference the `3885`.